# How to set tensorflow model restore exception

Tags: tensorflow

What I'm trying to do is add some features to the open source tensorflow model.

While doing that, I added new Variable by using `tf.Vriable` (not `tf.get_variable`)

At the same time, I'm trying to restore checkpoint because the model is hard to train on my computer.

The problem is this :

When I'm trying to restore parameters from checkpoint, NotFoundError Occurs. Error message is like this.

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key INITIAL_VAR not found in checkpoint
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Is there any way to set exception to prevent restoring from chekpoint for certain Variable?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I think I got the answer. When initializing tf.Saver, you can specify list of variables to save/restore by using `var_list` argument. I'll try it and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

All I wanted to do could be done by using `tf.train.Saver()`'s var_list argument.

I coded like this

```
variable_list = tf.global_variables()
variable_list.remove(variable_that_I_dont_want_to_restore)
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=variable_list)
saver.restore(sess,checkpoint)
```